Blazor Server. How do I connect to my API protected with [Authorize]? Works fine on my laptop but not on Azure
Edit: it's been suggested that I edit this question to differentiate it from previously answered questions. Others have noted that I shouldn't be using HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext in Blazor server but I've looked at all the suggested links and I can't find any other way to get cookies to authenticate with my API. My question is broader than this specific "null" issue. What I'm looking for is how to secure my API in a simple way without changing all the existing user authentication code in my Blazor server app because the rest of it is working well. Ideally I would like to keep using [Authorize(Policy = "Admins")] to secure my API as this is the same approach as the rest of my app. I just cannot figure out how to get it working on Azure. Here's my original question:
I have a Blazor server application. I created this using the template in Visual Studio for a Blazor Web App with Authentication Type = Individual Accounts. I have also added an API for users to download files. This is a business app and everything needs to be secured.
Here's what my API looks like:
[Authorize(Policy = "Admins")]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DataDownloadController : ControllerBase
{.....

And here's the code in my Blazor Server app that calls it:
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, fullUrl);  
var cookies = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;

foreach (var cookie in cookies)
    request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $"{cookie.Key}={cookie.Value}");

var response = await Http.SendAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{.....

It all works fine on my laptop but when deployed to an AppService on Azure things go wrong. HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is always null so I can't get the cookies. I get the feeling that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here. It seems silly that I have to manually deal with these cookies like this.
This data is not critically sensitive, and the API doesn't have any functionality to update data, so all I want is some kind of minimal security on this API without spending a huge amount of time on this. It would be really nice if I didn't have to change the existing account and security arrangements for the Blazor Server app because it's working nicely.
Thanks for helping. I've been stuck on this for hours and it's doing my frigin' head in!!
Here's my program.cs:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ErrorHandler>();         

    builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
        .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

    builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();  // seems to work OK without this but it's part of the default template
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

    // Added to get access to user obj
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(); // no idea if this is needed, gemini suggested this
    //builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, DefaultAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();

    builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                        .AddSignInManager()
                        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("LatzAdminPolicy", policy =>
            policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "IsLatzAdmin" && c.Value == "True")));
    });

    // This is my user utility service from the logic layer
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

    builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlOptionsBuilder =>
            sqlOptionsBuilder.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), errorNumbersToAdd: null));
    });

    builder.Services.AddQuickGridEntityFrameworkAdapter();
    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
    });

    builder.Services.Configure<LogoSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("LogoSettings"));
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<LogoSettings>>().Value);

    builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();
    builder.Services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AuthMessageSenderOptions"));
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSender<ApplicationUser>, EmailSender>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<EmailSender>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomEmailSender, CustomEmailSender>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomEmailSender>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<BlobStorageService>();
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        //The default HSTS value is 30 days.You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();


    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAntiforgery();
    // app.UseAuthentication();// ai reckons this isn't needed for blazor server, only normal asp.net 
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
        .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

    // Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
    app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}


This question is similar to: httpcontextaccessor null reference on app service but not debug. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for your help akseli but after checking all the suggested links I still can't find a solution.

You should enable app.UseAuthentication();, then we can use [Authorize(Policy = "Admins")].

Thanks Jason. I wasn't sure if I needed this or not. When I enable UseAuthentication, HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is still null. If I delete the code that uses this to get cookies then my Blazor app gets redirected to the login screen when it tries to access the API. Also when I click logout, I get this: AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.

Also, I should point out that I still get all these problems even if I change the attribute on my API to just [Authorize]. Is this approach meant to work at all???

I pulled my hair out for days over this. In the end I fixed it accidently while changing some other code. This API is used to download files. By calling it like this rather than with the code above it all started working. No need to look for cookies and add them manually. All so easy in the end. Phew!!!
Navigation.NavigateTo("myApiUrl", true);
